# Identify page nodes that have specific layout controller

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I would like to search all pages that have a specific(based on GUID) layout controller node. Is there a way to do this in Sitecore?

I am hoping to avoid going through all the page nodes and identifying the layout controller via the presentation detail. This would be a tedious tasks if I have to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also go to the layout in sitecore and click on the "Navigate" ribbon and use the "Links" menu option. The Referrers are the items that use the layout.

[image]

Comment: Thanks this helps. My next question would be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851705/remove-all-referrer-items-in-sitecore

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Development Center for it.

Go to the Sitecore Menu -> Development Tools -> Developer Center
Then, Select Tools -> XPath Builder.

The query you need is like this:

```
/sitecore/content//*[contains(@__Renderings, '{A5437488-E6FA-42D3-B201-25D3CFE0A02B}')]
```

Find all items that contain a specific id on the __Renderings field.

The __Renderings is a field like any other. It stores the information about the layou, devices and renderings. That said, you can use Sitecore queries to find items based on it. See:
[image]

Comment: Note that this method will not display items that use the rendering from the standard values of the template. Only if that rendering has been customized or added to the item.